# Is YAHOO.widget.DS_XHR able to load data cross-domain?

Tags: jquery, ajax, yui

I am trying to build an autocomplete script. The dictionary is on a separate domain and that seems to break the autocomplete.

I am use YAHOO.widget.DS_XHR to load the datasource, is it possible to use this function to load data cross-domain? If not is there another method I should be using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use YAHOO.widget.DS_ScriptNode() instead.

Answer (score 1):

No, because this functionality depends on the browsers restriction setting.